# Pass variable from NSTimer method to selector

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

I am a beginner with Objective-C, and unsure of how to pass a variable from my `startTimer` method to the selector. Why is my selector method not aware of the variable `circleSize` from `starTimer`? Thanks for the help.

```
- (void)startTimer:(int)circleSize
{

  self.clockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timerFired:(NSTimer *)clockTimer
{
  circleSize -= 1; // Error: Use of declared identifier

  NSLog(@"What is circle now?%i", circleSize);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the selector is not aware of the `circleSize` argument is because it is called asynchronously at some point in the future. As a result it will not have access to the scope that the `startTimer` method was called within. Add a breakpoint in each method and look at the stack trace and local variables to confirm for yourself.

You need to use an instance variable or a property to the containing class to store this information:

```
@implementation MyClass {
   int _circleSize;
}

- (void)startTimer:(int)circleSize
{

  _circleSize = circleSize
  self.clockTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (void) timerFired:(NSTimer *)clockTimer
{
  _circleSize -= 1; // Error: Use of declared identifier

  NSLog(@"What is circle now?%i", _circleSize);
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks, simple explanation. That did it.